# Как запретить прокручивание ViewPager

Tags: java, android, прокрутка, ui, android-viewpager

Есть ViewPager с фрагментами. В одном из фрагментов при определенных условиях включается и выключается обработка событий касания. При этом, когда обработка касаний включена, надо, чтобы ViewPager не реагировал на касания. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2):

```
//disable paging
mViewPager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

---

```
//enable paging
mViewPager.setOnTouchListener(null);
```

Comment: спасибо, работает.